# c++ codigo simple no arranca , no entiendo que esta mal en el código

Tags: c++

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    //realice un algoritmo que cuente los numeros de zapatillas de un almacen de 1 a 50 

    int cantzap =50;

    for(i=0; i<= cantzap; i++)
    {    
        if(i<30)
        {
            cout<<"encontre el treinta"<< 30;
        }

        cout<<"si se encontraron "<<cantzap<< endl;
    }
    cout<<"si se encontraron "<<cantzap<< endl;

}
```

Comment: En tu `if` tienes un `<` entrara del 0-29, imprimiendo `encontre el 30` 30 veces, supongo debería hacerlo solo una vez, en vez de un `<` pon un `==`, tampoco entiendo los dos ultimos `cout`, uno se ejecutara las 51 veces en el `for` y el ultimo una, haciendo que se repita el mensaje 52 veces, supongo que eso te refieres con que esta mal, o me equivoco?

Comment: Si indicas a qué te refieres con "No arranca", sería de gran ayuda para entender cuál es el problema.

Comment: si mira estoy usando codeblocks, para ejecutar el programa, pero ese ide, no ejecuta el codigo

Comment: Aunque debes de corregir varias cosas del programa, como por ejemplo que no se repita tanto el mensaje cuando encuentra un numero... El error principal que tienes es que **no has declarado la variable `i`** aqui: `for(i=0; i<= cantzap; i++)`

Comment: El código contiene errores que el IDE debe estar indicándote. Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir los mensajes de error o warnings que te esté mostrando (también los que aparezcan al compilar y/o ejecutar). Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes que declarar **i** y añadir un **=** en **if(i=30)** ya que el operador **=** es un operador de asignación. El de comparación es **==**. 
Aun así, es aconsejable utilizar un **else** para que solo cuando no se cumpla la condición imprima el mensaje *Encontré el treinta*. Por supuesto, para este caso debemos cambiar el **if(i==30)** por **if(i!=30)** e intercambiar el orden de los **cout <<...**.

En

```
for(i=1; i<=cantzap; i++)
```

*i* debe empezar por 1 ya que si no contaríamos 51 pares. De esta manera podemos sustituir *cantzap* por *i* en:

```
cout << "Se encontraron " << i << endl;
```

Así se irá mostrando el número real de zapatos que llevamos encontrados.

Otra cosa más es que las funciones ***int main()*** deben salir devolviendo un valor. Para eso utilizamos:

```
return 0;
```

Y por último, utilizar *\n* para introducir el salto de línea.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //realice un algoritmo que cuente los numeros de zapatillas de un almacen de 1 a 50 

    int cantzap =50;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=cantzap; i++)
    {
        if(i!=30)
        {
            cout << "Se encontraron " << i << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "\nEncontré el treinta\n\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "El total de zapatos encontrados es de "<< cantzap << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hola tengo una duda con el código, porque  en el código pones    
 if(i!=30) ,  eso no es diferente de 30 ?

Comment: Si hablamos de mi ejemplo, tal y como estaba la sentencia anterior el bucle siempre hacia el **if** y luego **else**. Pero las 50 veces. Como el 30 solo aparece una vez, cambiamos el orden de los ****cout...*** de  modo que a **else** solo se entre una vez. Y eso ocurre solo si la condición es del modo ***f(i!=30)***

Comment: Es muy importante saber que tipo de respuesta queremos ante una pregunta condicional. Podemos preguntar **¿Es blanco?** o preguntar **¿No es blanco?** y eso cambiará lo que siga a ***if(...)*** y a ***else***

Comment: gracias por la aclaración entiendo, voy a seguir practicando para que se me queda, me pasa que entiendo la teoria, pero a la hora de codear se me olvida

Comment: este es el código final:                                                                             
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int cantzap=50;
    int i;
    
    for(i=1; i<=cantzap; i++)
    {
    
        if(i!=30) // pones diferente de30
        {
        cout<<"se econtraron "<< i<< endl;  // encuentra todo
        }else
            {
            cout<<"encontro el treinta "<< i << endl; //aqui muestra nro 30
            }
    }
         cout<<"el total de zapatos es de  "<< cantzap<<endl;
           
}

Comment: quiero publicar el código final. no se como hacerlo para que se muestre con el fondo plomo ,como arriba , me ayudan

Comment: Cuando necesites poner algo como si fuese código puedes hacer dos cosas. Seleccionar el texto que quieres poner así y despues pulsar **Ctrl+k**. Si se trata de pocas líneas basta con ponerte al principio de cada línea **4 escapacios en blanco**, no intentes tabular porque no te funcionará. En los comentarios esto no es posible.

Comment: También debe haber una línea en blanco antes del código, si no, no aparecerá como código. Te aconsejo que edites alguna respuesta y mires, sin tocar, como lo han hecho otros.